# Why did these cosmonauts retire early in their careers?

Tags: history, astronauts

Is it known why Roman Romanenko and Dmitry Kondratyev retired early in their careers as cosmonauts?

Answer (score 4):

Romanenko retired [for health reasons](http://www.spacefacts.de/bios/cosmonauts/english/romanenko_roman.htm). I haven't found data on Kondratyev.

Answer (score 3):

According to [a newsru.com article (in Russian)](http://www.newsru.com/russia/06sep2012/mks.html) , Kondratiev quit cosmonauts corps and started to work for a private company, not related to space.

Another [article (also in Russian)](http://m.kp.ru/daily/26129/3021020/) contains an interview about Lonchakov's quitting the cosmonauts corps and also mentions that Kondratiev quit in protest against transferring [the cosmonaut training center](http://www.gctc.su/) from military to civilians (Kondratiev is a colonel of RF Air Force).